# Azure - Mobile Services - run background task every 10 seconds

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I have a .net backend mobile service in which I would like to run a task every 10 seconds. I can not use a scheduled job as they are limited to 60 seconds.

I have tried running the task in loop that aborts prior to the 60 second interval re-call, but that is not working out. The service seems to hang from time to time on the mobile device side/experience.

--

Does anyone understand how I can run a .net background task without using Scheduled Jobs?

Additionally, does anyone understand what happens when Scheduled Jobs call a service end point that has not returned or completed a previous call. Can this be detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scheduler that Mobile Services does not support what you are asking.  Best bet is to convert your job to a WebJob that runs continually and do the 10-second wait yourself.

See WebJobs: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-webjobs-resources/

Comment: Thanks Adrian... thought this might be the case.